# Determining Word boundaries using DirectWrite

Tags: windows, unicode, windows-runtime, directwrite, wordbreaker

DirectWrite provides line-breaking information via IDWriteTextAnalysisSink::SetLineBreakpoints(). However I need to determine word boundaries as well, in accordance with [Unicode Annex #29: Unicode Text Segmentation](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/).

Is there a way to do this using DirectWrite? If not, what alternatives are there that work alongside DirectWrite's text layout system in Windows desktop as well as WinRT?

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that DirectWrite up to Windows 8.1 does not support UAX 29 (just LB UAX 14). As for direct OS supplied alternatives, either Windows.Data.Text (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Text-Segmentation-API-be73de71) or the Extended Linguistic Services (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Extended-Linguistic-ELS-d04c606a) which has been around since Windows 7, may help, but I do not believe either of these support a direct implementation of UAX 29.